# derivative of a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling with the following task:

Let f: $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $$f(x_1,...,x_n)= \sum_{k,l=1}^n a_{kl}x_kx_l $$
when $a_{kl} \in \mathbb{R} \ \forall k,l \in $ {1,2,...,n} constant. Show that f is differentiable and calculate the derivative Df(x)  $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: What is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: I am not sure, but $2x_i$?

Comment: Try it for a specific $i$. What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} $?

Comment: I thought $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ is $a_{11}2x_1$

Comment: Write out the sum in full, say for $n=2$ or $n=3$, and try again. Then attempt to generalize to any $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Df(x) = \nabla f(x) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},..., \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 2a_{ii}x_i + \Sigma_{k=1, k\ne i}^{n}a_{ki}x_k$

Comment: I see, and f is differentiable at any x, because every partial derivative exists? Thanks!

Comment: That is correct and you are welcome.

Comment: @josh since you're new here, I thought I'd let you know about the "accept" feature of this site.  Basically, if a post has answered your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark to the left of the post.  This helps future readers know that the question is answered, rewards the answerer with +15 reputation, and adds +2 reputation to your own account.

Comment: Okay, I've just used this feature.